# IBM Blockchain Platform Extension is not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, ubuntu-20.04, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I just installed all the dependencies required to use the IBM Blockchain Platform extension on linux-Ubuntu. However, I'm facing some problems when trying to use it, the extension brokes right after I open my vscode.

Further, I've been searching to similiar problems and didn't find anything. As far as I know GLIBC is part of OS core so it's not a good idea do downgrade it to GLIBC 2.29.

I would appreciate your help on this guys, thanks in advance!

Dependencies installed:

- GLIBC:ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9) 2.31
- Node: v10.22.0
- npm: 6.14.6
- Docker: version 19.03.12
- Docker-compose: version 1.26.2
- vscode: 1.47.3

Error:

> Failed to activate extension: Failed to load /home/joaomassuia/.vscode/extensions/ibmblockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform-1.0.36/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/electron-v7.3-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node. /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/joaomassuia/.vscode/extensions/ibmblockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform-1.0.36/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/electron-v7.3-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably worth trying VS Code 1.39 as this might get the gRPC rebuild to begin - https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39

There is a known issue for some users with VS Code 1.40+ - https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/1621

Comment: It seems that it worked for me. I downgrade the VSCODE version and the extension activate process has been completed sucessfully. Thank you Jake!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs with VS Code installed from Snap. It goes away if VS Code is installed from the .deb file in the VS Code download [site](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).